# How to remove the default "Successfully deleted ..." message for "Delete Selected" in Django Admin Action?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-messages, django-admin-actions

In the overridden [delete_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.delete_queryset), I deleted loaded messages and added **the new message "Deleted successfully!!"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from .models import Person
from django.contrib import admin, messages

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    def delete_queryset(self, request, queryset):
        msgs = messages.get_messages(request)

        # Delete loaded messages
        for i in range(len(msgs)):
            del msgs[i]
        
        # Add a new message
        self.message_user(request, "Deleted successfully!!", messages.SUCCESS)

        queryset.delete()
```

Then, when clicking **Go** to go to delete the selected persons as shown below:

[image]

Then, clicking **Yes I'm sure** to delete the selected persons:

[image]

But, **the default message "Successfully deleted 2 persons."** is not removed as shown below:

[image]

So, how can I remove the default message for `Delete Selected` in Django Admin Action?

Comment: Probably you better plug in a different delete action: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/actions.py#L52-L57

Comment: Or just override the translation with something where you omit the parameters.